# What are the implications of the fact that radian measures of angles are real numbers?

Tags: angle

Let's say that we proved that the radian measures of angles are real numbers (i.e. if we have an angle $x \text{ rads}$, then $x \in \Bbb R$) since the radian measure of an angle $\theta$ is the length of the arc that subtends an angle of $\theta$ at the centre of a unit circle and the lengths attain real values only. [A good way to visualize this is by drawing a number line tagential to a point on the unit circle and then 'warping' the line along the circle's circumference].

Now, why do we prove this? I would like to know about the implications of this result?

Thanks!

Comment: It is no more profound than saying we can measure "distances" by two real numbers on the number line by the magnitude of their distance.  That's all.

Comment: Note that lengths can only be positive whereas angles can be negative as well.

Comment: @AkshatSharma Good point, but the magnitude is always positive, right? A negative angle is different from a positive angle only in terms of the direction that the initial side is rotated along to reach the terminal side.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That clarifies it, thanks!

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Yes, that's true.